# WebView show load dialog?

Tags: android

I am not sure why onPageFinished doesn't kick it when page is loaded? The loading dialog just keep on showing despite the fact that the page is loaded how to fix that?

I want dialog to disappear once the page is loaded!

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        WebView web;
        ProgressDialog dialog;

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            //Hide Title Bar    - This Should be done before SetContentView

            this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            // Inflation

            web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

            web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

                // This method will be triggered when the Page Started Loading

                public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, null,
                            "Please Wait...Page is Loading...");
                    dialog.setCancelable(true);
                    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                }

                // This method will be triggered when the Page loading is completed

                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                }




            });
            web.loadUrl("http://google.com");
            web.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            web.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
            // enabling javaScript
            WebSettings webSettings = web.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: buddy thanks but the dialog wont be showing and that's the whole  point. How can i fix it and still showing dialog i dont really want to show text only spinning circle. Could you show me how

Comment: You were right buddy thanks so much very appreciate this. But now it doesn't work on internal links!!!! How to make it work on internal links too?

Comment: buddy thanks so much

Comment: How do I incorporate that spinner into my code please help me here?